# Assessing a multiple conditions

Tags: r

I am wondering whether there is a better method to assess all conditions are true:

```
lapply(1:5, function(a){
  assign(paste0("a",a),a,envir =globalenv())
})

isTRUE(a1<a2 & a2<a3 & a3<a4 & a4<a5)
```

The above works, but I like to know if there is a better and more concise method to ascertain it. I am looking for a method where I don't have to type all the variables (a1, a2, etc) and the vector/list can be checked whether it is in ascending order. Although I've given integers as values for variables here, the idea is to check dates.

Something like this?

```
isTRUE(a1<a2<a3<a4<a5)
# Or
ll<-list(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
is.ordered(ll)

## I think this works!
ll<-c(a2,a1,a3,a4,a5)

ll<-c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
ordering<-order(ll)
all(ll==ll[ordering])
```

Comment: Avoid the `is.ordered` and use `!is.unsorted`. `is.ordered` is for factors. See `help("is.ordered")`. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Further, you likely want to use `&&` and not `&` to stop evaluating after you reaches the first `FALSE`. See `help("&&")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ideas

```r
> #####
> # solution with ...
> f <- function(...){
+   dots <- list(...)
+   if(length(dots) == 1)
+     return(TRUE)
+   if(..1 >= ..2)
+     return(FALSE)
+   do.call(f, dots[-1])
+ }
> 
> f(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
[1] TRUE
> 
> # you can use ls to find args
> args <- lapply(ls(pattern = "^a\\d+"), as.name)
> do.call(f, args)
[1] TRUE
> 
> #####
> # your list idea
> args <- lapply(ls(pattern = "^a\\d+"), as.name)
> !is.unsorted(do.call(c, args)) # assume result is same type with `c` method
[1] TRUE
> 
> #####
> # make expression and evaluate
> args <- ls(pattern = "^a\\d+")
> tmp <- mapply(paste, args[-length(args)], args[-1], sep = " < ")
> expr <- parse(text = paste0(tmp, collapse = " && "))
> expr
expression(a1 < a2 && a2 < a3 && a3 < a4 && a4 < a5)
> eval(expr)
[1] TRUE
```

You can likely do something smarter which each of them that works faster.

Comment: In terms of performance of the frist solution than I gather one could dig into [this question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/stopifnot-does-not-stop-at-first-non-TRUE-argument-td4733312.html) called _stopifnot() does not stop at first non-TRUE argument_ to make a better solution.